# VPC logs way too many, how can I reduce the number?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-kinesis

I am getting way too many VPC logs, as in over 100k an hour for one VPC. Any way to reduce this? I have the `MaxAggregationInterval: 600` but that's still not cutting it. Would the only thing be to do is stream to kinesis and perform additional aggregation? Not really ideal.

Comment: At the moment I am leading towards using a CloudWatch LogGroup FlowLog type, and then use a subscription filter pattern to select only a subset of logs.

Comment: For Flow Logs you can specify a filter to indicate the type of traffic to capture (accepted traffic only, rejected traffic only or all traffic). Do you want to log only rejected traffic? Another option is to configure Flow Logs at specific subnets level or even specific ENIs you want to analize traffic metadata

Comment: Ideally I wanted all the logs but once I saw for 1 VPC I was getting 100k logs an hour, that was a no go. So next best thing is a subset of traffic. Rejected is not that interesting it wouldn't show dodgy traffic which made it through.